Session Storage Directory in Laravel
Reading the Laravel 11 documentation I saw that sessions are stored in storage/framework/session, however according to the CIS Benchmark Guidelines this is somewhat unsafe, and our project has to follow some of these guidelines.
Does Laravel allow me to change the session directory to something like /tmp ?

While the provided answer does show how to change the directory, there is no need to. Even though the cited audit is marked as deprecated, the default directory can pass the audit just fine. The default directory is a single purpose directory, it is outside of the document root, and you can set the permissions on it as described.

Yes, Laravel will allow you to change session directory, In your config/session.php
'files' => '/tmp',

